# Not able to add a data repeater to panel in site.com

Tags: site.com, data-repeater

I have created a design for a web site it contain different panels. For design i have add a big panel in which there are 4 small panels. Now i am trying to add data repeater to the panels 1 by 1 but i am not able to add data repeater to 3 of the panels i am only able to add the data repeater to the panel which i have added at the last.
Structure of my site.com
[image]

Issue that i am facing 
[image]

i have created the Quick link then tweets then  profile completeness and then at last i have created company feed, so i am only able to add data repeater to company feeds not to any other panel. 
[image]

Please guide me what need to be changed or what are the way to add data repeater.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a template-based page, make sure that all your panels are editable (I suspect your other 3 panels are NOT editable). Such pages only allow adding elements such as data repeaters to an editable panel. You can read more about Editable Panels and how to add elements to them [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_objects_add.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: AnuRaj - Did this fix your issue?